# PHP MySQL update database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and mysql
I want to crate a query that does the update or adds a new table if it is not in database

So far I have this and why do I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING for

```
mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0);
```

Can you help me to make this code work? When I comment all the mysql_quer only I get blank page 
and
      echo "ID $trenutnired does not exist in table and: $countUpdated
";

is not working?

I use PHP 5.2.17

Thanks

```
    <?php


     $mysql_db = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_pwd  = "";


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $mysql_user, $mysql_pwd);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $con);

      $countUpdated=0;

        mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product_shop prod_shop INNER JOIN ps_product prod USING(id_product) SET prod_shop.id_category_default = prod.id_category_default WHERE prod_shop.id_product BETWEEN 1 AND 62226);

                mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product_supplier SET id_currency = 3 WHERE id_currency = 0);                      
                mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0);
                mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product_shop SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0);


    $kveri = "SELECT id_product,id_supplier,supplier_reference, wholesale_price FROM ps_product";

    $ispis = mysql_query($kveri) or die(mysql_error());

               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ispis)){


               $trenutnired = $row['id_product'];
               $trenutnired1 = 0;
               $trenutnired2 = $row['id_supplier'];
               $trenutnired4 = $row['supplier_reference'];
               $trenutnired5 = $row['wholesale_price'];
               $trenutnired6 = 3;


               $drugatab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = '$trenutnired'");

               $dalipostoji = mysql_num_rows($drugatab);

               if ($dalipostoji == 0) {

               echo "ID $trenutnired does not exist in table and:: $countUpdated<br />";   

                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier (id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier, product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  VALUES ('', '$trenutnired', '$trenutnired1',  '$trenutnired2', '$trenutnired4', '$trenutnired5', '$trenutnired6')");

                                   $countUpdated++;

               };
             }               
    ?>
```

Comment: Please remember to sanitize any user input as well before sending it to the db. Mysql_real_escape_string() is a good start.

Comment: @mehnihma and, please know that in this site, if you get the answer to your questions, you can upvote your choice to mark them as **Answered.** Because, it seems you are unaware of such thing.

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check if your query was successful before continuing script execution because on production servers error reporting is usually disabled (as it should be) so you won't be able to see errors in your code like in this case where you actually tried to fetch the number of records for an unsuccessful query.

I.e. you should have checked if your `SELECT` query actually returns a result like this.

```
$drugatab = "SELECT * FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = '$trenutnired'";
if($rezultati = mysql_query($drugatab) && mysql_num_rows($rezultati)){
    // Successful query...
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier (id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier, product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  VALUES ('', '$trenutnired', '$trenutnired1',  '$trenutnired2', '$trenutnired4', '$trenutnired5', '$trenutnired6')");
    $countUpdated++;
} else {
    echo "ID $trenutnired ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: $countUpdated<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Now I got "else" that no IDs exists in other table but only 20 are missing?

Comment: Try adding `echo mysql_error();` right above the `echo "ID..."` line because you obviously have an error inside your query.

Comment: I need to list only that are not in first table ps_product and INSERT them only, how can I do that?

Comment: With error I get this error for every record:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #4964' at line 1ID 5260 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 0

Comment: Check the updated answer. I made a mistake by calling `mysql_query` on a resource.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get:
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home2/public_html/shop/dokumenti/up2.php on line 53
ID 1 ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: 0

Comment: Do you now the problem maybe>?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have forgotten to put double `"` after `mysql_query(`

Have you tried this:

`mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0 ");`

Instead of

`mysql_query(UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0);`

***Check below for the whole code*** (modified)

---

```
<?php


     $mysql_db = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_pwd  = "";


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $mysql_user, $mysql_pwd);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db($mysql_db, $con);

      $countUpdated=0;

      //popravak kategorija
        mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product_shop prod_shop INNER JOIN ps_product prod USING(id_product) SET prod_shop.id_category_default = prod.id_category_default WHERE prod_shop.id_product BETWEEN 1 AND 62226 ");


                // sve na kunu
                mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product_supplier SET id_currency = 3 WHERE id_currency = 0");


                //dodavanje poreza

                mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0");
                mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product_shop SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0");



    //$kveri = "SELECT id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier,product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency FROM ps_product";
    $kveri = "SELECT id_product,id_supplier,supplier_reference, wholesale_price FROM ps_product";

    $ispis = mysql_query($kveri) or die(mysql_error());

               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ispis)){


               $trenutnired = $row['id_product'];
               $trenutnired1 = 0;
               $trenutnired2 = $row['id_supplier'];
               $trenutnired4 = $row['supplier_reference'];
               $trenutnired5 = $row['wholesale_price'];
               $trenutnired6 = 3;



                                                            //echo $trenutnired;

               $drugatab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = '$trenutnired'");

               $dalipostoji = mysql_num_rows($drugatab);




               if ($dalipostoji == 0) {

               echo "ID $trenutnired ne postoji u drugoj tablici i trenutno: $countUpdated<br />";   

                 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ps_product_supplier (id_product_supplier, id_product, id_product_attribute, id_supplier, product_supplier_reference, product_supplier_price_te, id_currency)  VALUES ('', '$trenutnired', '$trenutnired1',  '$trenutnired2', '$trenutnired4', '$trenutnired5', '$trenutnired6')");

                                   $countUpdated++;



               };


             }

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that but still I get blank page
 echo is not outputing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this script? because, I feel like it could be improved and be made simpler.

Comment: To update some values in database and to insert values from one table if they are missing in other table

Comment: `mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group ='22' WHERE id_tax_rules_group ='21'"); or die(mysql_error());  `

Comment: @mehnihma 
Then simply run the above code in your page (paste the code, and refresh your page, to understand if the problem is from database details or your codding)

Comment: @mehnihma Did you get your problems solved for you

Comment: No it still does not work, now I get Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Answer (score 2):

That error indicates a problem in your PHP. Specifically, the `mysql_query()` function takes a *string* as its first argument. So you'll need to wrap your SQL statement in quotes:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ps_product SET id_tax_rules_group = 1 WHERE id_tax_rules_group = 0");
```